# Socially responsible surveillance?

Tags: justice

Surveillance is an ever hotter topic - surveillance of communications and/or metadata and of physical spaces (i.e. cameras).

I'm strongly sympathetic to the privacy advocacy movement - not because I think I particularly have anything to hide but because (theoretically) the underdog politicians/leaders that I might support now *or in the future* very likely would need privacy from whatever institution they oppose.  And then there are the people who work to protect those leaders and the ones who help organize those protectors and then the ones who might fund the entire outfit.  Someone in power with access to surveillance materials would have an additional advantages (besides incumbency) to interfere with contenders personally, professionally, legally, etc.

Still, not all mysteries can be solved by old-fashioned investigative work - some crimes will be solved by surveillance materials that would not be solved without them.  And it would be the very unfortunate case that falsely-compelling surveillance evidence would lead to an honest but unjust judgement.

Rather than choosing between two futures - one where surveillance is prevalent and available for review by government powers, and the other where government surveillance is minimal (or owned privately at direct private expense) and those crimes go unsolved - is there a practical middle ground where the responsibility to provide surveillance infrastructure is isolated from the ability to review those recordings?

Instead of CCTV cameras being operated and reviewable by the police, for example, what if the police or other civilians operate the cameras yet the camera hardware actually encrypts directly on hardware to public keys owned by the judicial branch and exposed only with merit.

For phone metadata, I've heard of schemes using anonymized metadata and network analysis for useful preventive or investigative work - but then I've also heard of researchers triangulating real identities out of seemingly anonymized social networks.  But again, what if the stuff got recorded into a lockbox that only the judiciary can open under a warrant (whether or not they actually physically store the stuff)?

No matter what the digital evidence, criminal penalties could be severe for people or companies intercepting/redirecting/copying these confidential materials (captured by publicly owned cameras, for example).  And the judiciary, of course, could also be corrupt, but ideally their whole mission and purpose and structure - if society has any hope - is to always seek and provide for justice - so while enforcers are out finding better ways to enforce, justices are focused on practices/procedures that protect rights and preserve fairness.

(Also, it isn't so far-fetched to me that a judicial branch of government would be charged with hosting the secure technology infrastructure for this purpose.  Every branch of government has a supporting technology infrastructure and should have a competent staff capable of running it.  And the hope is that the mission and culture and precautionary measures of that organization can keep its privileged agents in line).

I realize that surveillance can be used for preventing crime in a direct, anticipatory way or it can be used for catching culprits of a crime that already took place.  This mechanism probably moves too slowly for the preventive kind.  Though perhaps if you have enough exposed surveillance evidence and enough muscle you can deter even the most evil adversary.

Is there a surveillance scheme that all sides (among the informed and benevolent) could find just, useful, sustainable, and balanced?  Is there something fundamentally useless about a separation of powers scheme?  Is there something logically, technologically, game-theoretically, economically infeasible about securing surveillance (in the large) from abuses?

Comment: There's a lot of text here, but it looks like this is more of a request for a technology than it is a discussion of the philosophical side of surveillance.  The question could be sufficiently philosophical if it was reduced to "what forms of surveillance have been deemed (just|balanced) by philosophers?"  As written, I think it is too technologically oriented.

Comment: It's not about tech besides that the issue and any solutions might be tech based.  Instead, it is about the limits of a society to cooperate for good, societal trust, and the core/source of the dangers of surveillance.  On a long enough timeline, does it matter who holds the power?  Is abstinence the only strategy?  Are security and privacy necessarily at odds?

Comment: I wonder if giving this power to the judiciary gives it too much power. Might it help to use [secret sharing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) (e.g. Shamir's Secret Sharing)? With secret sharing, three parties are involved: the judiciary, the law enforcement, and the premise owner. Decrypting the video requires at least two parties to agree to it. No single party can unlock the video unilaterally.

Comment: During a preliminary investigation of a third party crime, the police and the owner agrees to investigate and unlock the video (without needing warrants); when investigating police malpractice, the owner and the judiciary agrees (this is presuming that the judiciary and the law enforcement aren't corrupt together); if there's investigation of the premise owner's crime, the police and the judiciary agrees to unlock (essentially a form of digital warrant).

Comment: Could you cut this down and highlight the question you have that's answerable in an SE format? (For starters, the first two paragraphs seem like they could clipped).

Comment: If you can re-edit it to focus on the philosophical question that we might be able to answer, then I think there's the possibility of an articulate and interesting question about balancing freedom and safety in a democratic state.